Rewrite rule to other directory with content
I have the following Nginx configuration:
root /usr/share/nginx/files;

location / {
    #root /usr/share/nginx/files;
    autoindex on;
}

location /gallery {
    rewrite "^(/gallery)/[A-Za-z0-9]{8}/([0-9]{1,4}\.jpg)$" $1/$2 break;
    autoindex on;
}

Directory gallery with images is located in /usr/share/nginx/files.
I would like to have one more location that will use images from gallery directory.
I've tried to do it in different ways:
location /new {
    rewrite "^/new/[A-Za-z0-9]{8}/([0-9]{1,4}\.jpg)$" $document_root/gallery/$1 break;
    autoindex on;
}

But without luck. I get error message that such directory or file doesn't exist.
Could you please advise what proper way to access directory with content using different locations?

Remove $document_root from the rewrite statement.

Ah, it works, thanks! @RichardSmith, should I add extra rule to access image via new location without random string [A-Za-z0-9]{8} in the path? Now all works for request http://server/new/q1w2e3r4/0.jpg, but I get 404 for http://server/new/0.jpg.

I've slighly modified regex in rule: rewrite "^/new/([A-Za-z0-9]{8}/)?([0-9]{1,4}\.jpg)$" /gallery/$2 break;
